Visual Studio IntelliSense Fails to Recognize Method in Base Page for ASPX .NET Framework Project
I'm working on an ASPX project using .NET Framework in Visual Studio 2022. My pages inherit a base class BasePage, which contains a helper function GetVersionedPath. Here's the relevant setup:
Page:
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="analitica.aspx.vb" Inherits="VisualIntelligence.analitica" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/Sidebar.ascx" TagName="Sidebar" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<link href="<%= GetVersionedPath("../assets/styles/dashboard.min.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" />

Code-Behind for the Page:
Public Class analitica
    Inherits BasePage

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Request.Cookies("jwt_token") Is Nothing Then Response.Redirect("../Login.aspx")
        If TokenManager.GetPrincipal(Request.Cookies("jwt_token").Value) Is Nothing Then Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class

Base Page:
Public Class BasePage
    Inherits Page

    Private Shared _version As String

    Protected ReadOnly Property Version As String
        Get
#If DEBUG Then
            Return Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
#Else
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(_version) Then
                _version = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AppVersion")
            End If
            Return _version
#End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Function GetVersionedPath(relativePath As String) As String
        Return $"{ResolveUrl(relativePath)}?v={Version}"
    End Function
End Class

The application runs without issues, and the GetVersionedPath function works as expected at runtime. However, Visual Studio 2022 displays the following IntelliSense error for the <%= GetVersionedPath(...) %> usage in the ASPX file:
BC30451: 'GetVersionedPath' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.


My Environment:

Visual Studio 2022
.NET Framework 4.7.2

What could be causing IntelliSense to fail in recognizing GetVersionedPath, even though the application runs fine? How can I resolve this?

There's no legitimate reason to continue to target .NET 4.7.2 - you should retarget to 4.8 and do a full clean+build - which will also probably fix the problem too.

@Dai even after an upgrade to 4.8 the problem still persists..

If you change the access level of this function GetVersionedPath to public and reload your project, will the issue persists?

What is the detailed version of your Visual Studio 2022? I did a quick test in VS17.12.2 and could not reproduce the issue. If it's possible, could you share a sample to help me reproduce?

@DouXu-MSFT I am using VS17.11.6, btw I will try to make a sample project and will share it with you so you will be able to reproduce. I've tried even to set GetVersionedPath to public but nothing change.

@DouXu-MSFT While I was trying to create a new project with an example for you, I've notice that a newly created project does not have that issue, so it should be a project related issue, maybe that the base project was .NET Framework 3.5 or idk...

@DouXu-MSFT After a further update to 4.8 and the update of all NuGets dependencies, the issue seems resolved.

Hi @NiceToMytyuk, glad to hear that you have resolved the issue. If possible, you can add an answer here. This will help other users who has the same issue and someone else find the solution easily. Just a reminder.   ;)
